# Como permitir somente leitura para determinado tipo de usuário?

Tags: c#, .net

Eu tenho um botão em que dispara um evento para fechar ano letivo de uma escola. Ao clicar nesse botão, a pessoa pode ter acesso a todas as telas do sistema, porém não pode editar nada, excluir, inserir. Tem algum jeito de bloquear somente essas funções para o usuário para não ter que validar tela por tela do sistema?

Comment: Complicado dizer detalhes sem conhecer o seu sistema.

Comment: Mas tem alguma forma de fazer uma validação "geral" sem ter que validar tela por tela?

Comment: Não está clara essa parte da validação. É um problema da interface de usuário? O usuário não consegue trocar de tela porque não dá dados suficientes preenchidos, e dá erro de validação? É isso? A pergunta está bem vaga, por favor use o link de [edit] abaixo dela e tente incluir mais informações relevantes.

Comment: @StoneSour Seu sistema é ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Não, vamos supor o seguinte: eu tenho um botao que fecha o ano letivo, depois que fecha nada mais pode ser feito, como lançamento de notas, exclusão de matérias, essas coisas. Validação para isso eu sei fazer, só gostaria de saber se tem um jeito de eu validar isso de forma geral, sem ter que ir em tela por tela e verificar se o ano foi fechado...

Comment: O seu sistema é MVC5 ?

Comment: Não, eu não uso MVC.

Comment: Já que você não está usando ASP.NET MVC, poderia indicar qual tecnologia está usando?

Comment: Ops, fiz lambança com as tags, me desculpem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando Windows Forms, no Form você pode declarar um variável global chamada TipoUsuario e depois cria um método para fazer a verificação e caso o tipoUsuario não for o administrador mudar a propriedade Enable de cada Form.

Comment: boa, eu estou usando WebForm, mas foi desse jeito que fiz, após logar eu verifico se o mes ja foi fechado e atribuo a uma Session, e fiz uma classe que seta enable false pra todos os componentes da pagina, mas isso nao me impede de mexer em todas as telas para fazer a verificação, mas pelo menos o trabalho é menor, é só chamar o método de validação no PageLoad. Obrigado.

Comment: tenho uma dúvida, eu passo enable = false pra todos os componentes button da minha página, porem, quado esse button estád entro de um Panel eu não consigo setar false pra ele, teria um outro jeito?

Comment: Se for possível mostrar seu código ficará mais fácil de entender o problema.

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria algo assim (ASP.NET MVC em Razor + jQuery):

```
@section scripts {
    @if (User.IsInRole("Diretores")) {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input, select, textarea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```